# when to use FragmentActivity and Activity with Android x

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, androidx

I am a bit confused with Activity and FragmentActivity. MinimumSDKVersion for my app is 21 - Lolipop. And I have read that FragmentActivity should be used if the app support is below honeycomb.

I am using Androix x support package.

So should I be using getSupportFragmentManager with FragmentActivity or getFragmentManager using just the Activity

if my app does not support bellow honeycomb I donot need to use FragmentActivty or is this required if I use Android X

R

Comment: You can use AppCompatActivity as your base activity, it supports fragment transactions & backward compatible

Comment: Theoretically you could just use the `Activity` and `getFragmentManager`. Practically everyone use the `AppCompatActivity` and the `getSupportFragmentManager`. (`AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`)